# automator and python script utf-8 output

Tags: automator, python, utf-8

I wrote a python shell script and it fails in automator workflow :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib, json, os, datetime
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR')

url = "http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/lefakir/ws?count=8"

urllib.urlopen(url)

deliciousFeed = urllib.urlopen(url)

posts = json.load(deliciousFeed)

for post in posts:
    print " * {0} : [{1}]({2})".format(post["n"], post["d"], post["u"])
```

The problem occurs on post["n"] and post["d"] which have utf-8 symbols.

Is it a common issue ?

Comment: Please can you add details about the error message you see and how you are using this script with Automator.

Comment: Yes, this is a common issue. UTF-8 and Python quite often don't play nice.

Comment: Sorry @GrahamMiln it's in french : http://grab.by/FrIG, but you can copy/paste this code in automator i think.

Comment: @JohnKeates do you mean with automator or in a more general way ?

Comment: With Python in a more general way. Unicode support requires some additional work to play nice with python. I learned this the hard way while working with SaltStack.

Comment: I think that automator can't handle the unicode type, let's continue

Answer (score 1):

I found myself :

```
print " * {0} : [{1}]({2})".format(post["n"].encode( "utf-8" ), post["d"].encode( "utf-8" ), post["u"].encode( "utf-8" ))
```

It was an unicode/utf-8 problem :)